# Embedded picture with separate coordinate system (Tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

Am using Tikz, and have a slightly complicated drawing. Now I want to replace a rectangle in a certain place with a more sophisticated shape. This shape I have in SVG format, and I want to replace the dozen or so SVG path instructions with Tikz commands, ie remove the SVG entirely.

So, I have a rectangle with position x,y and size wd,ht in the original Tikz picture, where I want to put a bunch of line and curve commands which use a different coordinate system.

**Edit**: I want to (for example) replace

```
\draw (x1,y1) rectangle (x2,y2);
```

with

```
\draw (x1,y1) mypic (x2,y2);
```

where `mypic` is defined in terms of a different coordinate system, and has some given size in that coordinate system, and can be assumed to have the appropriate relationship between the axes, ie I am not interested in different "scaling" for x and y.

Is there a way to accomplish this without recalculating anything, or explicitly "scaling" or anything like that?

I want to just define my new shape in a macro or something and then use it, and everything is automatic.

What is the simplest solution?

([This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/how-can-i-draw-a-tikz-element-multiple-times-against-a-shaded-background) is similar but not identical.)

Comment: Like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/121799)? This allows you to install a local coordinate system.

Comment: I believe you will have much better chances of getting a concrete answer if you make your question more concrete by adding a code that illustrates what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I had a look at your updated question and at the link you shared. The [last answer in the list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151772/121799) states that there are `pic`s for that. Are you familiar with `pic`s? See e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445815/121799) for a use case. You can make `pic`s depend on parameters.

Comment: With `pic`, I still need to define the coordinate transformation, apparently.