# Define more complex shapes for nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I often need to make of diagrams involving cells and/or other medium complex shapes. At the for this I work with nodes, since they are easy to position and to connect. To make the cell shapes I use additional `tikzfigure` enviroments within the nodes. See the following minimal example.

This is not optimal and I wonder if there is a simpler solution. I tried `\pic` put they are less flexible than nodes. Probably `\pgfdeclareshape` would be the way to go, isn't? But this is a little too complicated for my to figure out. Is there an easy explanation or another solution? The simplest would be to make a `tikzstyle` for the whole cell.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzstyle{cytosol} = [thick, draw=red!60, fill = red!20, ellipse, minimum width=35, minimum height= 22, align=center, rotate = 30]
\tikzstyle{nucleus} = [thick, draw=olive!80, fill = brown!20, circle, minimum width=10, align=center]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[] (Cell1) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[cytosol] at(0,0) (cytosol) {};
            \node[nucleus, shift={(0.15,0.1)}] () at(cytosol) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}{}
    };

    \node[right of= Cell1, xshift = 1 cm] (Cell2) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[cytosol, draw=gray!40, fill = gray!60] at(0,0) (cytosol) {};
            \node[nucleus, shift={(0.15,0.1)}] () at(cytosol) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}{}
    };

    \node[right of= Cell2, xshift = 1 cm] (Cell3) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[cytosol] at(0,0) (cytosol) {};
            \node[nucleus, shift={(0.15,0.1)}] () at(cytosol) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}{}
    };

    \draw[->] (Cell1) --(Cell2); 
    \draw[->] (Cell2) --(Cell3); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This results in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Small images `pic` cross my mind  ...

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create node "shapes" using \pgfdeclareshape, but everything is done using the basic level commands (\pgfpathmoveto, \pgfpathlineto, etc.)  The big decision is whether to include text, and to make the shape expand to fit the text.  If not, the code can be much simpler.

Comment: I don't include text in this kind of nodes. So fitting to text is not necessary.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445815) (ironically coming from a related subject) gets you going? In any case, your current method nests `tikzpicture`s which should be avoided by all means. Also, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: I already had a look at `pic` and they look really helpful. The one thing that I struggle is, that I don't know how you can easily connect different `pics` with arrows

Comment: I just figured out that it is possible to connect nodes within `pic` with arrows. This could solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options to achieve this. You could use `pic`s, as mentioned in the comments, cf. e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/445815). Here is a somewhat more exotic possibility: use a `path picture`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{cytosol/.style={thick, draw=red!60, fill = red!20, ellipse, minimum
width=35, minimum height= 22, align=center,rotate = 30},
nucleus/.style={path picture={\draw[draw=olive!80,fill = brown!20,#1]
    ([xshift=0.15cm,yshift=0.1cm]path picture bounding box.center) 
     circle[radius=5pt];}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[start chain=Cell placed {at={(\tikzchaincount*2,0)}},
    nodes={on chain,join= by {semithick,-stealth}}]
  \node[cytosol,nucleus]{};
  \node[cytosol, draw=gray!40, fill = gray!60,nucleus]{};
  \node[cytosol,nucleus]{};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the option `nucleus` adds the dot. Other exotic options include `append after command`.

Please note also that your code nests `tikzpicture` environments, which really should be avoided, and `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the problem with the nested pictures, this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. The `path picture` looks interesting I will have a look at it.